# Accessing Control from Custom Event Handler in Custom WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, events, event-handling

I am using **VS2010**, **WinForm**

I had to create a class which will output a windows form. I made it for doing some action in that form and finally pass some value to its parent. Sending data to the parent part is done well. I have tested and satisfied.

But when i want to have some action in between the same form i have made, here creates a problem. I want to create event and tell what these event will do. i generated event handler and can go to the event also. but **in the event handler i cannot access any of my control i created**. I just want to have the access of all control i have created in the **Show** method From my event **buttonConnectServer_Click**

Here is my Code:

**CustomSettingBox.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

namespace ServerConnector
{
    class CustomSettingBox
    {
        ConnectionSettings CS = new ConnectionSettings();

    public List<string> GetServerName()
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Settings//ServerList.txt");
        string line = "";
        List<string> lstServerName = new List<string>();
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
             lstServerName.Add(line.Trim());
        }
        sr.Close();
        return lstServerName;
    }





**public void buttonConnectServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { MessageBox.Show("Done!");   `//this message is succesfully shown. but i cannot get access any of my controls defined in Show() method.`

        }**

    public DialogResult Show(ref string ServerName, ref string AuthenTicationType)
    {
        Form form = new Form();

        Label labelServerName = new Label(); //otherlabels here

        TextBox textBoxLogin = new TextBox(); //other textboxs here

        ComboBox comboboxServerName = new ComboBox(); //more combo's

        ListBox listboxAllColumn = new ListBox(); // more listbox's

        Button buttonConnectServer = new Button();
        Button buttonOk = new Button();
        Button buttonCancel = new Button();

        form.Text = "Add Setting";
        labelServerName.Text = "Select a Server";//other labels are defined


        List<string> lstServerName = GetServerName();//gets servername from a text
        foreach (string tmp in lstServerName)
        {
            comboboxServerName.Items.Add(tmp);
        }

        comboboxAuthenticationType.Items.Add("Wndows Server Authentication");
        comboboxAuthenticationType.Items.Add("SQL Server Authentication");


        buttonOk.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        buttonCancel.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;


        **buttonConnectServer.Click +=new System.EventHandler(this.buttonConnectServer_Click);**

        labelServerName.SetBounds(9, 20, 100, 13);//others are here

        comboboxServerName.SetBounds(120, 20, 200, 30);//others are here

        //comboboxServerName.SetBounds(12, 75, 372, 27);
        buttonOk.SetBounds(228, 450, 75, 23);
        buttonCancel.SetBounds(309, 450, 75, 23);

        labelServerName.AutoSize = true;//otheres are here

        comboboxServerName.Anchor = comboboxServerName.Anchor | AnchorStyles.Right; // others are here

        buttonConnectServer.Anchor = buttonConnectServer.Anchor | AnchorStyles.Right;
        buttonOk.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;
        buttonCancel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;

        form.ClientSize = new Size(600, 500);
        form.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { labelServerName, labelAuthenticationType, labelLogin, labelPassword, labelDbName, labelTableName, labelSelectColumn, labelWhereColumn, comboboxServerName, comboboxAuthenticationType, textBoxLogin, textboxPassword, comboboxDbName, comboboxTableName, listboxAllColumn, listboxSelectColumn, listboxWhereColumn, buttonConnectServer, buttonOk, buttonCancel });

        form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        form.MinimizeBox = false;
        form.MaximizeBox = false;
        form.AcceptButton = buttonOk;
        form.CancelButton = buttonCancel;

        DialogResult dialogResult = form.ShowDialog();

        ServerName = textBoxLogin.Text;
        AuthenTicationType = comboboxServerName.SelectedItem.ToString();
        return dialogResult;
    }
}
```

}

as i have no problem with designs, i tried to avoid most of the designing code here, as it is going larger.

Comment: How do you try to access them and from where?

Comment: I want to access from **buttonConnectServer_Click()**. And access all the controls i declare in the **Show** method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to access local function variables from another function. You must declare them as global variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can either declare your control variables as fields in your parent form, or assign their `Name` properties and access them using the `Find` method:

```
form.Controls.Find("control name", true);
```

(so long as you declare `form` as a field in the parent form).